# How to deal with a constant value as an output from neural network?

Tags: neural-network, keras, training, optimization

I am using feedforward neural network for regression and what I get as a result of prediction is a constant value visible on the graph below:[image: output from my NN]

Data I use are typical standardised tabular numbers. The architecture is as follows:

```
model.add(Dense(units=512, activation='relu', input_shape=x_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(units=256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.1)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam)

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor='val_loss',
    factor=0.9,
    patience=10,
    min_lr=0.0001,
    verbose=1)

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs\{}".format(NAME))

history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    epochs=500,
    verbose=10,
    batch_size=128,
    callbacks=[reduce_lr, tensorboard],
    validation_split=0.1)
```

It seems for me that all weights are zeroed and only constant bias is present here, since for different data samples from a test set I get the same value.

I understand that the algorithm has found smallest MSE for such a constant value, but is there a way of avoiding such situation, since straight line is not really good solution for my project?

[EDIT]
Adding learning curves for trainging and validation sets.
[image]

Comment: So this is not an LSTM model? Since your data looks like classical time series, LSTM would be the first thing to try, IMO. Your regress towards the mean as it appears.

Comment: It is not LSTM, however model has some lagged features. I used LSTMs for similar data and eventually ended up with same problem. However before that I have not noticed any big difference in the results.

Answer (score 1):

Lowering the initial learning rate from 0.1 to 0.005 helped the problem.

```
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.005)
```

Answer (score 0):

However, the post is kinda old I've dealt with similar situation using PyTorch. Normalizing data should help. I assume this is because all your values are strictly positive so subtracting mean should improve your network as it differs "lower" and "higher" values.